# cURL with Terminal for AWS Ec2

Tags: php, curl, amazon-web-services

So I just switched from some network solutions hosting running some php files that return JSON. when I run the same curl terminal command to the new server it does not respond the php errors like it did before. What do I need to do to enable it so it returns the errors in the terminal with curl?

**Update** it appears it's returning a HTTP Error 500. How can I show the errors instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, i edited `/etc/php.ini` to `display_errors = On;`